# Como posso fazer o cálculo da largura ao redimensionar uma imagem que deve ser 3 X 4, sabendo apenas a altura?

Tags: php, matemática, processamento-de-imagens

Uso o `PHP` para poder fazer tratamento de imagens num determinado sistema.

Preciso que as fotos contenha a proporção de 3x4.

O sistema funciona assim:

1 - O usuário tira a foto da webcam.

2 - Um ajax é enviado para o PHP processar essa imagem.

3 - A imagem é redimensionada para `3x4`, mas a altura padrão deve ser `478`.

Preciso saber como eu posso saber qual é a largura que terei que definir para essa imagem quando eu for redimensioná-la, sendo que eu só tenho a altura, pois não quero ficar colocando números fixos, quero deixar o calculo pronto, para que, se eu alterar a altura, a largura seja ajustada dinamicamente.

Qual é o cálculo que devo usar em PHP para saber qual é o largura de uma foto 3x4, baseada apenas na altura?

O código que eu tenho atualmente é esse:

```
 class Solicitacao {
     const IMAGE_HEIGHT = 478;
 }
```

Na criação da imagem, eu faço assim:

```
   $imageString = base64_decode(Input::get('file'));

   Gregwar\Image\Image::fromData($imageString)
                      ->resize($largura_dinamica_aqui, Solicitacao::IMAGE_HEIGHT)
                     ->save('temp.png', 'png');
```

Comment: Você jura que vai fazer essa pergunta?

Comment: @Wallace, temos que fazer diferente, da forma que esta teremos imagens comprimidas horizontalmente assim perdendo a proporção, sugiro que altere sua pergunta e fazermos um sistema de corte de imagem, onde o usuário pode escolher o retângulo na proporção 3x4 da parte da imagem que deseja salvar, mais ou menos como o Instagram faz, mas no seu caso em um retângulo, e não quadrado.

Comment: @bigown só queria ver se iriam complicar ou simplificar.

Comment: @bigown  já fiz a  pergunta, kkkkk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que Matemáticamente é:

3x4:

```
Comprimento -> 3
Altura -> 4
```

Ou seja, suponhamos que temos uma altura de 600px e não sabemos o comprimento:

```
(600 * 3) / 4 = comprimento
```

Já deve saber, mas para adquar ao seu código será:

```
....
(IMAGE_HEIGHT * 3) / 4 = $width
resize($width, IMAGE_HEIGHT)
```

Comment: Isso é regra de três básica! Fácil, fácil!

Comment: Acho que era o foco da dúvida do nosso colega

Comment: É verdade que é fácil, eu já sei a resposta. Mas ainda acho que você fez do jeito mais difícil

Comment: Exatamente Miguel! Direto no ponto!

Comment: Obrigado, para este contexto a sua solução está ainda melhor @Wallace Maxters

Comment: Pode até ser @Miguel, mas como o bigown disse é ruim dar um código pronto e a pessoa não saber o que ele faz. Acho que o meu -1 foi merecido

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado pelas respostas, mas eu gostaria de deixar um jeito simples. P

Quando fui dar uma pesquisada nesse cálculo, vi contas para lá e para cá para poder fazer isso, mas pode ser resolvido de um jeito muito mais simples. Para bem dizer "com uma linha".

Se pensarmos na lógica:

```
 3/4 = 0.75
```

Basta então fazermos  uma multiplicação para acharmos o resultado em PHP:

```
 $width = Solicitacao::IMAGE_HEIGHT * 0.75; // 358.5
```

Comment: Isto não é necessariamente mais simples. Claro quem alguma simplificação. Mas há simplificações que não são desejáveis. Não está errado, e eu sei o que é este 0,75, mas não é tão óbvio para todos. Muitos programadores optariam por deixar as duas operações para indicar claramente que é um cálculo de proporção. Alguns inclusive teriam usado constantes no lugar de 3 e 4 para evitar os tais "números mágicos" e dar mais semântica ainda ao que está fazendo. Outros até usariam variáveis, melhor ainda, parâmetros e fazer com que o cálculo seja genérico para qualquer proporção.

Comment: O trabalho do programador até é simplificar, mas também é abstrair, generalizar, de principalmente escrever código legível. A pergunta não fala nada em escrever o código mais simplificado possível. Parece Code Golf, só que oculto, só quem fez a pergunta sabe a resposta.

Comment: Ok Senhor @bigown. Obrigado pelas suas dicas ;)